# Why are there no equations of the form $a/b/c$ in Physics (or science)?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

If you look through the Wikipedia page of physical quantities, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_physical_quantities , you never see any equations of the form $a/b/c$. Why is that? You can multiply as many dimensional quantities as you can, but it seems that you're always limited to one division.

Because everything else is so algebraically defined, there's should be no reason that you can't take it to the extreme. So as an example, what would an equation like meters/second/kilogram even mean? It's algebraically defined. It's very unsatisfying to never see any equations like that, because what if there is a very useful equation of that form but we're too focused on the $a/b$ form?

Comment: A Pascal is a kilogram per metre per second squared.

Comment: $a/b/c$ is not an example of an equation.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{a}{b/c} = \frac{ ac}{b}
$$
$$
\frac{a/b}{c} = \frac{a}{bc}
$$